# Spring boot Rest create a category which can reference to another category or not

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I have an entity class

```
public class CategoryEntity implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String categoryKeyId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    //Here mappedBy indicates that the owner is in the other side
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductEntity> products;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CategoryEntity parent;

    // allow to delete also subcategories
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CategoryEntity> subCategories;
}
```

**this class generates this SQL code :**

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `category_key_id` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKsaok720gsu4u2wrgbk10b5n8d` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So far, so good it's perfectly what i'm expecting. My issue concerns how to create a new category.

**My DTO layer is :**

```
@Getter @Setter
public class CategoryDto implements Serializable {
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private int parentCategoryId;
    private String categoryKeyId;
    private String name;
    private List<CategoryDto> subCategories;
    private CategoryDto parentCategory;

}
```

I also created 2 Rest Model for creating categories one for the request and the other for the response. 
**I need to provide a json as entry with the name and the parent category id:**

```
@Getter @Setter
public class CategoryCreateRequestModel {
    private String name;
    private int parentCategory;
}
```

**And i retrieve a json as output :**

```
@Getter @Setter
public class CategoryCreateRest {
    private String categoryKeyId;
    private String name;
    private CategoryCreateRest parentCategory;
}
```

My createCategory method returns the output result i expect and takes a CategoryCreateRequestModel as input.

```
@PostMapping(
        consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
        produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
) 
public CategoryCreateRest createCategory(@RequestBody CategoryCreateRequestModel categoryCreateRest) throws Exception {
    CategoryCreateRest returnValue = new CategoryCreateRest();

    if( categoryCreateRest.getName().isEmpty())
        throw new NullPointerException(ErrorMessages.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS.getErrorMessage());

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    CategoryDto categoryDto = modelMapper.map(categoryCreateRest, CategoryDto.class);

    CategoryDto createdCategory = categoryService.createCategory(categoryDto);
    returnValue = modelMapper.map(createdCategory, CategoryCreateRest.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

My service layer :

```
@Override
public CategoryDto createCategory(CategoryDto categoryDto) {
    // check if category name and parentId are identicals
    if (categoryRepository.findByName(categoryDto.getName()) != null)
        throw new ApplicationServiceException("Record already in Database");

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    CategoryEntity categoryEntity = modelMapper.map(categoryDto, CategoryEntity.class);

    // generate categoryKeyId
    String categoryKeyId = utils.generateCategoryKeyId(30);
    categoryEntity.setCategoryKeyId(categoryKeyId);

    CategoryEntity storedCategory = categoryRepository.save(categoryEntity);

    CategoryDto returnValue = modelMapper.map(storedCategory, CategoryDto.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

When i set a new category for example:

```
{
  "name": "catName",
  "parentCategoryId": 12
}
```

or

```
{
  "name": "catName",
  "parentCategoryId": null
}
```

I obtain a 500 error message : could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"

Apparently I have issues with the primary key and I don't see what is going wrong. I should not need to pass an id to this json because it should be automatically generated.

Comment: Try adding some generation technique of `id` on db side (e.g. `auto_increment`)

Comment: You are damn right ! I had to change AUTO with IDENTITY... Unfortunatelly i didn't solve the category parent...

Comment: It would be useful adding hibernate version and which dbms you use in description